# Not seeing any information on the new daily reputation page

Tags: support, profile-page, reputation-graph

Having just received an up-vote I thought I'd double check where from:

[image: got an up-vote!]

So I click on the reputation link and get this:

[image: no details]

The URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf?tab=reputation&startDate=2011-03-11&endDate=2011-03-12`

I can see that there is supposed to be some data there, but apart from today's date I get nothing. This is happening on all sites. Operating system is Windows XP SP3. Browser is Chrome v 10.0.648.127

On sites where I haven't received any votes it correctly says:

> There were no reputation changes for the selected days

NOTE: I have *never* been able to get the reputation graph to display data for anything less than a couple of days as nothing ever happens when I enter dates into the fields. I have to use the mouse to drag the selection and that's never accurate.

**UPDATE**

From other questions and @Grace's comment it's clear that other people can see their page OK. What would be interesting would be if I could check someone else's profile page. Can someone post a link.

**UPDATE 2**

It appears to be working now.

Comment: I agree this is a big problem - right now I'm not able to even see what answers were voted on - very hopefully this is not by design!

Comment: Inexplicably, *I* am able to see your values when viewing the graph, even though you can't. So if you were curious, you've gotten upvotes on [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815057/experiences-with-kentico-cms/815069#815069 "Probably that lone vote you haven't found yet") and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273674/cross-thread-exception-when-setting-winforms-form-owner-how-to-do-it-right/5273698#5273698).

Comment: @Grace - I've checked using the old `http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/59303` url. But thanks!

Comment: Yech, hate this. All I see is the graph, which I have no interest in. Votes are scrolled off the bottom of my screen. It seems to take a lot of clicks to get to comments, which I am most interested in.

Comment: This is probably a new feature: Anyone with rep over 25k should intrinsically know where their rep was gained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed.

I've never seen any feedback as to what the problem was - or whether it was specific to me only.

Will accept this answer to stop the question being bumped by the Community user in the future.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought the same thing. Then I scrolled down a bit further and saw the rep votes correctly displayed below the graph. Not very friendly, IMO. Screen shot added for reference.

Win7 Chrome v 10.0.648.127

[image: SO Graph]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting today's date in the space where the history should be. As I've just noted in the question I acknowledge that others can see their and my page. I'd like to see if I can see someone else's.

Comment: **PLEASE NOTE** When this answer was posted **I couldn't see the reputation summary**. I just got the date. This answer doesn't address my problem.